# Orbeon upload component active in read mode?

Tags: file-upload, orbeon

SOLVED - I have an upload component in section of an Orbeon form (in Liferay portal). Users have to upload a document here in the first stage of the workflow.

Later in the workflow, when this section of the form is in read-only mode, the upload button can still be used to upload something. Afterward uploading there is no evidence in the form of any upload (no file name), either of the original upload or the one later committed in read-only mode.

On clicking "Download" the original upload is downloaded, not the file that seemed to be uploaded when in read-only mode.

Is this a known bug, is there anything we can do about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a known issue, and it is [fixed in Orbeon Forms 4.5](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1105).